# Paypal Payment Recieve Successfully But Get Payment Failure Message

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

On my site i use paypal standart. I made a real test and payment recieved succesfull but get payment failure message on my system.
Also results are same on **Paypal IPN similator.**

Details;
My IPN file;

```
      <?php
class PayPal extends PaymentAPIHandler {
    var $gateway_name = 'PayPal';
    var $test_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    var $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
...
....
 /**
    * Verify Response
    * Check to make sure the response is valid and not fraudulent
    * @return boolean
    */
    function verifyResponse() {
        if(isset($this->response['tx'])) {
            if(!empty($this->settings['paypal_pdt_token'])) {
                $parameters = 'cmd=_notify-synch&tx='.urlencode($_GET['tx']).'&at='.urlencode($this->settings['paypal_pdt_token']);
                $http_request = $this->PMDR->get('HTTP_Request');
                $http_request->settings = array(
                    CURLOPT_HEADER=>0,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
                    CURLOPT_POST=>1,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$parameters,
                    CURLOPT_CAINFO => PMDROOT.'/includes/cacert.pem',
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('Host: www.paypal.com')

                );
                $response = $http_request->get('curl',$this->url);
                $response_parts = explode("\n", preg_replace('/\r\n|\r/', "\n", $response));
                if($verified_response = array_shift($response_parts) != 'SUCCESS') {
                    if(!is_null($http_request->error_number)) {
                        $this->errors[] = $http_request->error_message;
                    }
                    $this->errors[] = 'Invalid response: '.$verified_response;
                    $this->errors[] = 'Sent Parameters: '.$parameters;
                    unset($verified_response);
                    return false;
                }
                unset($verified_response);
                foreach($response_parts as $part) {
                    $value = explode('=',$part);
                    if($value[0] != '') {
                        $this->response[$value[0]] = urldecode($value[1]);
                    }
                }
            } elseif($this->response['st'] != 'Completed') {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $parameters_ignore = array('cmd');
            $parameters = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
            foreach ($this->response as $key=>$value) {
                if(in_array($key,$parameters_ignore)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $parameters .= "&$key=".urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            }
            unset($parameters_ignore);
            $http_request = $this->PMDR->get('HTTP_Request');
            $http_request->settings = array(
                CURLOPT_HEADER=>0,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
                CURLOPT_POST=>1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$parameters,
                CURLOPT_CAINFO => PMDROOT.'/includes/cacert.pem',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('Host: www.paypal.com')
```

and erros in payment gateway log in my system ;

```
payment_type => instant

payment_date => Fri Jun 12 2015 23:50:27 GMT+0300 (GTB Yaz Saati)

payment_status => Failed

address_status => confirmed

payer_status => verified

first_name => John

last_name => Smith

payer_email => buyer@paypalsandbox.com
payer_id => TESTBUYERID01

address_name => John Smith

address_country => United States

address_country_code => US

address_zip => 95131

address_state => CA

address_city => San Jose

address_street => 123 any street

business => seller@paypalsandbox.com

receiver_email => seller@paypalsandbox.com

receiver_id => seller@paypalsandbox.com

residence_country => US

item_name => something

item_number => AK-1234

quantity => 1

shipping => 3.04

tax => 2.02

mc_currency => USD

mc_fee => 0.44

mc_gross => 12.34

mc_gross1 => 12.34

txn_type => web_accept

txn_id => 644696571

notify_version => 2.1

custom => xyz123

invoice => abc1234

test_ipn => 1

verify_sign => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AwghKO7W8eQu9tuhieamEKWpf7PS

Errors:
Invalid response:

Access Denied

You don't have permission to access
 http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr on this server.
Reference #18.d7b874e.1434142529.4860b30
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what log you are getting an access denied permission on; your server should not be accessing that PayPal link; webscr is what serves web pages for PayPal, so your buyer should be accessing it from their browser, but you should not be accessing it. Whatever writes to the log in question is doing something wrong. Look there....

Comment: I am still not sure what this log is you are quoting from. Is it written by your PHP process? You seem to be implying this but it doesn't exactly square with the quoted code. Note that the URL being accessed is http, not https. What is attempting to access that URL? It shouldn't be your IPN postback. And what is printing (or generating) that string "You don't have permission...."? Are you believing that it is in the $verified_response in your code above?

Comment: yes it written by my PHP. i use phpmydirectory.com directory script.

Comment: fixe it ; by add `'Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'`